How can I solve this problem with ChromeDrive?
I have this code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\dchrome\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.smv.gob.pe/SIMV/')

time.sleep(3)

driver.quit()

And I don't know why do I have these errors:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Sebas\OneDrive\Escritorio\Visual Studio Code\Python\index.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\dchrome\chromedriver.exe')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\OneDrive\Escritorio\Visual Studio Code\Python\RT_IL\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\OneDrive\Escritorio\Visual Studio Code\Python\RT_IL\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    if finder.get_browser_path():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\OneDrive\Escritorio\Visual Studio Code\Python\RT_IL\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 47, in get_browser_path
    return self._binary_paths()["browser_path"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\OneDrive\Escritorio\Visual Studio Code\Python\RT_IL\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 56, in _binary_paths
    browser = self._options.capabilities["browserName"]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'
PS C:\Users\Sebas\OneDrive\Escritorio\Visual Studio Code> & "c:/Users/Sebas/OneDrive/Escritorio/Visual Studio Code/Python/RT_IL/Scripts/python.exe" "c:/Users/Sebas/OneDrive/Escritorio/Visual Studio Code/Python/index.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Sebas\OneDrive\Escritorio\Visual Studio Code\Python\index.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\dchrome\chromedriver.exe')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\OneDrive\Escritorio\Visual Studio Code\Python\RT_IL\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\OneDrive\Escritorio\Visual Studio Code\Python\RT_IL\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    if finder.get_browser_path():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\OneDrive\Escritorio\Visual Studio Code\Python\RT_IL\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 47, in get_browser_path
    return self._binary_paths()["browser_path"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\OneDrive\Escritorio\Visual Studio Code\Python\RT_IL\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 56, in _binary_paths
    browser = self._options.capabilities["browserName"]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'


I checked the address of my driver
I checked the versions


You might want to check out webdriver_manager package.
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.smv.gob.pe/SIMV/')

time.sleep(3)

driver.quit()

